# Registration form - creating new entries to a table

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

im trying to create a table that collects data from a registration form and wanted to add a couple lines (zip,state,etc..) The code works fine(name, email, username,etc..) besides the lines i added. Any idea why the others get moved fine and the newest entries do not get moved they just seem to disappear.

**UPDATE: 5-2-13 11:07AM EST 
Error when submitting form**

```
 Error inserting data to the table
query:insert into users(
name,
lastname,
email,
username,
password,
zipcode,
country,
phonenumber,
address,
city,
state,
confirmcode
values
(
"Lucas",
"Weir",
"lucas@12miletechs.com",
"qualitygoods11",
"2aeac48777d7d33ac22cb0c1bac45bf3",
"48178",
"Usa",
"248xxx8851",
"XXXX Hen Rd.",
"South Lyon",
"MI",
"18456d8a76e3337cebb1fec161c50291"
)
mysqlerror:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values
(
"Lucas",
"Weir",
"lucas@12miletechs.com",
"qua' at line 14
Inserting to Database failed!
```

CODE:

```
function CollectRegistrationSubmission(&$formvars)
        {
            $formvars['name'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
            $formvars['email'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);
            $formvars['username'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['username']);
            $formvars['password'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['password']);
            $formvars['lastname'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['lastname']);
            $formvars['zipcode'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['zipcode']);
            $formvars['country'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['country']);
            $formvars['phonenumber'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['phonenumber']);
            $formvars['address'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['address']);      
            $formvars['city'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['city']);
            $formvars['state'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['state']);
        }

function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
{

    $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

    $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

    $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
            name,
            email,
            username,
            password,
            zipcode,
            country,
            phonenumber,
            address,
            city,
            state,
            confirmcode
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
            "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['zipcode']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['country']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['phonenumber']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['address']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['city']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['state']) . '",
            "' . $confirmcode . '"
            )';      
    if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
        return false;
    }        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Take a variable that isn't working (you mentioned zip code) and do a var_dump($formvars['zipcode']) right before the query in the InsertIntoDB function. See what you are sending to the function. It may be that your html form is the issue.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION is what i got on the line i just put in. Is there any special formatting i should do around it? i just copied and pasted it right above InsertIntoDB

Comment: I think you should paste the var_dump code just above if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection)) and not right above InsertIntoDB function declaration.

Comment: still giving me the same error ive been playing around but no luck. any other suggestions?

Comment: it took the command but nothing happened no output? wouldn't it pop up or something?  It just continued as if i didn't even insert the command.

Comment: So you can't see any output from var_dump command yes? It wouldn't pop up probably. You can try something like echo 'Hello'; and put it above if(!mysql_query... If you can't see the Hello message from echo, it means that for some reason the function is not executed.

Comment: no output is correct. i have made some progress but now this is showing when i submit the form:

Answer (score 0):

Count your database columns ;) In the query (in the output you posted in update) there are 12 columns, but in VALUES statement afterwards are only 11 columns (probably lastname is missing). Edit your PHP code (add lastname value) and the query should run without problems.

Comment: Nice catch but i added the lastname column and still getting the same error? any ideas? thanks for the help

Comment: i just noticed i was missing the country box on my form i'll update the code above with the current error im getting now.

Comment: Ok, I get same error when I run it as plain SQL code. The error can be fixed by adding a ) before values statement. However, in your code it appears that there is the ). Strange...

Comment: Try adding a space before values statement and also try encapsulating field names in `.

Comment: as in a space you mean a new line? and encapsulate the values or the insert into table part above that?